# 5.1 output not working on Lubuntu

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, lubuntu

I recently installed Lubuntu 17.04 and tried to connect it to 5.1 audio system but I only get two channels. Well, not quite - the center and the subwoofer do make some weak sound but there are no dedicated signals to them. I edited my `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` as many recommend online, in particular changed `; enable-lfe-remixing` to both `= yes` and `= no` to `enable-lfe-remixing = yes` and `; default-sample-channels=2` to `default-sample-channels=6` but still no luck. Here is how `daemon.conf` looks currently:

```
; daemonize = no
; fail = yes
; allow-module-loading = yes
; allow-exit = yes
; use-pid-file = yes
; system-instance = no
; local-server-type = user
; enable-shm = yes
; enable-memfd = yes
; shm-size-bytes = 0 # setting this 0 will use the system-default, usually 64 MiB
; lock-memory = no
; cpu-limit = no

; high-priority = yes
; nice-level = -11

; realtime-scheduling = yes
; realtime-priority = 5

; exit-idle-time = 20
; scache-idle-time = 20

; dl-search-path = (depends on architecture)

; load-default-script-file = yes
; default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa

; log-target = auto
; log-level = notice
; log-meta = no
; log-time = no
; log-backtrace = 0

; resample-method = speex-float-1
; enable-remixing = yes
; enable-lfe-remixing = no
; lfe-crossover-freq = 0

flat-volumes = no

; rlimit-fsize = -1
; rlimit-data = -1
; rlimit-stack = -1
; rlimit-core = -1
; rlimit-as = -1
; rlimit-rss = -1
; rlimit-nproc = -1
; rlimit-nofile = 256
; rlimit-memlock = -1
; rlimit-locks = -1
; rlimit-sigpending = -1
; rlimit-msgqueue = -1
; rlimit-nice = 31
; rlimit-rtprio = 9
; rlimit-rttime = 200000

; default-sample-format = s16le
; default-sample-rate = 44100
; alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 6
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe

; default-fragments = 4
; default-fragment-size-msec = 25

; enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
; deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
```

I also wanted to mention that my PC dosen't have an HDMI plug so I use an displayport to HDMI converter cable. And this is what I use for [5.1 deembedding](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DZXQV4M). But I don't think any of this is the reason because the signal seems to leave the PC as a two channel signal - the output of `pacmd list-sinks` still shows two channels:

```
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
```

Here is the last part of the output of `amixer -c0 contents`

```
numid=30,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map',device=2
  ; type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0
  | container
    | chmap-fixed=FL,FR

numid=36,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=3
  ; type=BYTES,access=r--v----,values=32
  : values=0x10,0x00,0x07,0x00,0x69,0x12,0x00,0x4f,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x34,0xac,0xc8,0x31,0x4d,0x45,0x55,0x53,0x50,0x54,0x56,0x31,0x31,0x09,0x7f,0x07
numid=37,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=3
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=8,min=0,max=36,step=0
  : values=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
  | container
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR,LFE
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR,FC
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR,RL,RR
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR,LFE,FC
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR,LFE,RL,RR
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR,FC,RL,RR
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR,LFE,FC,RL,RR
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR,RL,RR,RLC,RRC
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR,LFE,RL,RR,RLC,RRC
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR,FC,RL,RR,RLC,RRC
    | chmap-variable=FL,FR,LFE,FC,RL,RR,RLC,RRC
```

Here are the results of the some interrogation. Taking pulseaudio out does not change anything.

Output of `aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev1 Analog [ALC662 rev1 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Output of `lspci -nn`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller [8086:0100] (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0102] (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1c3a] (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller [8086:1c3d] (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1c2d] (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1c20] (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1c10] (rev b4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:1c18] (rev b4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 7 [8086:1c1c] (rev b4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 [8086:1c1e] (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1c26] (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Q67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller [8086:1c4e] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller [8086:1c02] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1c22] (rev 04)
```

Output of     `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*`

```
Codec: Realtek ALC662 rev1
Address: 2
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x10ec0662
Subsystem Id: 0x103c1496
Revision Id: 0x100101
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=2, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x1d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Line Out Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC662 rev1 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x40 0x40]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x1d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x40 0x40]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x1d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x40, nsteps=0x40, stepsize=0x03, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x05 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x06 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x211: Stereo Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital:
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Node 0x07 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x08 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10011b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC662 rev1 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x09, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x1f 0x1f]
  Converter: stream=1, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0x6]: 16 20
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Connection: 1
     0x23
Node 0x09 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x10011b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=1, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=1, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="ALC662 rev1 Alt Analog", type="Audio", device=2
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x09, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0x6]: 16 20
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Connection: 1
     0x22
Node 0x0a [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x0b [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Mic Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Mic Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=1, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Line Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x17, nsteps=0x1f, stepsize=0x05, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x1f 0x1f] [0x1f 0x1f] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 9
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x14 0x15 0x16
Node 0x0c [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x02 0x0b
Node 0x0d [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x03 0x0b
Node 0x0e [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 2
     0x04 0x0b
Node 0x0f [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x10 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x11 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x12 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x13 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x14 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Line Out Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0001003c: IN OUT HP EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x01014010: [Jack] Line Out at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Green
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Connection: 1
     0x0c
Node 0x15 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00010034: IN OUT EAPD Detect
  EAPD 0x2: EAPD
  Pin Default 0x99130120: [Fixed] Speaker at Int ATAPI
    Conn = ATAPI, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0d
Node 0x16 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00000034: IN OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0e
Node 0x17 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x18 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Line Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00001734: IN OUT Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80
  Pin Default 0x01813c30: [Jack] Line In at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Blue
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=04, enabled=1
  Connection: 1
     0x0e
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000173c: IN OUT HP Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80
  Pin Default 0x02a11c3f: [Jack] Mic at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0xf
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=03, enabled=1
  Connection: 2
     0x0c* 0x0e
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018d: Stereo Amp-Out
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x00000034: IN OUT Detect
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Connection: 1
     0x0d
Node 0x1b [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40018f: Stereo Amp-In Amp-Out
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x27, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Pincap 0x0000173c: IN OUT HP Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 50 GRD 80
  Pin Default 0x0221101f: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Front
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0xf
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Connection: 2
     0x0c 0x0e*
Node 0x1c [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400001: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
Node 0x1d [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400000: Mono
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x40028101: [N/A] Line Out at Ext N/A
    Conn = 1/4, Color = Purple
    DefAssociation = 0x0, Sequence = 0x1
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
Node 0x1e [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400300: Mono Digital
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x411111f0: [N/A] Speaker at Ext Rear
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Connection: 1
     0x06
Node 0x1f [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x20 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00040: Mono
  Processing caps: benign=0, ncoeff=12
Node 0x21 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x22 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 10
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x0b
Node 0x23 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20010b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x00 0x00] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80] [0x80 0x80]
  Connection: 10
     0x18 0x19 0x1a 0x1b 0x1c 0x1d 0x14 0x15 0x16 0x0b
Node 0x24 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x25 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x26 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Codec: Intel CougarPoint HDMI
Address: 3
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 0)
Vendor Id: 0x80862805
Subsystem Id: 0x80861496
Revision Id: 0x100000
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x0]:
    bits [0x0]:
    formats [0x0]:
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D3 CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0, Clock-stop-OK
GPIO: io=0, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=0, wake=0
Node 0x02 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x03 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=5, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x04 [Audio Output] wcaps 0x6611: 8-Channels Digital
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  Digital: Enabled
  Digital category: 0x0
  IEC Coding Type: 0x0
  PCM:
    rates [0x7f0]: 32000 44100 48000 88200 96000 176400 192000
    bits [0x1e]: 16 20 24 32
    formats [0x5]: PCM AC3
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x05 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x80]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x58560010: [N/A] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x02
Node 0x06 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Con Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Pro Mask", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Default", index=0, device=0
  Control: name="IEC958 Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x18560020: [Jack] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x03
Node 0x07 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40778d: 8-Channels Digital Amp-Out CP
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x00, stepsize=0x00, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x00 0x80]
  Pincap 0x09000094: OUT Detect HBR HDMI DP
  Pin Default 0x58560030: [N/A] Digital Out at Int HDMI
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 1
     0x04
Node 0x08 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
```

**Update:**

At one point, I somehow rebooted with 5.1 deembedder turned off. I went to `pavucontrol` and under the "Profile" in the configuration tab, I saw the option "Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output 5.1 (Unplugged)"!!! But there was no sound at all. So I turend the 5.1 deembedder on and rebooted the machine. The 5.1 HDMI option disappeared. Not sure what is going on, but with the deembedder turned on, the 5.1 option disappears.

**Update 2:**

Here is the output of `hexdump /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/edid` with the switch at 5.1, 2.0, and pass, and they all look the same to me (the PC was rebooted each time just in case).

5.1:

```
0000000 ff00 ffff ffff 00ff ac34 31c8 0101 0101
0000010 130d 0301 a280 785b 242a ae71 474c 26aa
0000020 5010 2154 0008 c0d1 c08b 8081 c081 c066
0000030 c04b 0001 0001 3a02 1880 3871 402d 2c58
0000040 0045 8d50 0063 1e00 1d01 1880 3871 402d
0000050 2c58 0045 8d50 0063 1e00 0000 fd00 3b00
0000060 0f3d 1144 0a00 2020 2020 2020 0000 fc00
0000070 4d00 5545 5053 5654 3131 200a 2020 6e01
0000080 0302 f128 9047 2022 0405 0103 0923 077f
0000090 4f83 0000 036c 000c 0021 2da8 0000 0000
00000a0 e300 0305 e201 7f00 1d01 3e80 3873 402d
00000b0 2c7e 8045 8d50 0063 1e00 1d01 1880 1c71
00000c0 2016 2c58 0025 8d50 0063 9e00 1d01 7200
00000d0 d051 201e 286e 0055 8d50 0063 1e00 0a8c
00000e0 8ad0 e020 102d 3e10 0096 8d50 0063 1800
00000f0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1800
```

2.0:

```
0000000 ff00 ffff ffff 00ff ac34 31c8 0101 0101
0000010 130d 0301 a280 785b 242a ae71 474c 26aa
0000020 5010 2154 0008 c0d1 c08b 8081 c081 c066
0000030 c04b 0001 0001 3a02 1880 3871 402d 2c58
0000040 0045 8d50 0063 1e00 1d01 1880 3871 402d
0000050 2c58 0045 8d50 0063 1e00 0000 fd00 3b00
0000060 0f3d 1144 0a00 2020 2020 2020 0000 fc00
0000070 4d00 5545 5053 5654 3131 200a 2020 6e01
0000080 0302 f128 9047 2022 0405 0103 0923 077f
0000090 4f83 0000 036c 000c 0021 2da8 0000 0000
00000a0 e300 0305 e201 7f00 1d01 3e80 3873 402d
00000b0 2c7e 8045 8d50 0063 1e00 1d01 1880 1c71
00000c0 2016 2c58 0025 8d50 0063 9e00 1d01 7200
00000d0 d051 201e 286e 0055 8d50 0063 1e00 0a8c
00000e0 8ad0 e020 102d 3e10 0096 8d50 0063 1800
00000f0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1800
0000100
```

Pass:

```
0000000 ff00 ffff ffff 00ff ac34 31c8 0101 0101
0000010 130d 0301 a280 785b 242a ae71 474c 26aa
0000020 5010 2154 0008 c0d1 c08b 8081 c081 c066
0000030 c04b 0001 0001 3a02 1880 3871 402d 2c58
0000040 0045 8d50 0063 1e00 1d01 1880 3871 402d
0000050 2c58 0045 8d50 0063 1e00 0000 fd00 3b00
0000060 0f3d 1144 0a00 2020 2020 2020 0000 fc00
0000070 4d00 5545 5053 5654 3131 200a 2020 6e01
0000080 0302 f128 9047 2022 0405 0103 0923 077f
0000090 4f83 0000 036c 000c 0021 2da8 0000 0000
00000a0 e300 0305 e201 7f00 1d01 3e80 3873 402d
00000b0 2c7e 8045 8d50 0063 1e00 1d01 1880 1c71
00000c0 2016 2c58 0025 8d50 0063 9e00 1d01 7200
00000d0 d051 201e 286e 0055 8d50 0063 1e00 0a8c
00000e0 8ad0 e020 102d 3e10 0096 8d50 0063 1800
00000f0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1800
0000100
```

Comment: Did you use 5.1 sound sources/files (which ones?), or do you expect stereo sources to be upmixed? What does `speaker-test` do when you use the `-c` resp. `-s` options?

Comment: @dirkt yes I downloaded a few sample 5.1 video files where you can also see visually which speaker should be active. Also tried `speaker-test -t wav -c 8` which shows good front left and front right response, the center response comes out of front left and right (the center speaker itself responds to both fronts and center but it is very diminished). I don't have rears connected at all (amp is not workin). The LFE (subwoofer) signal doesn't trigger the subwoofer response but overall subwoofer responds to its range of sound of 2.0 output (richer spectrum but still 2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to take Pulseaudio out of the equation. Stop pulseaudio with `pulseaudio --kill` or whatever LUbuntu requires, or use `pasuspender`. Look at `alsamixer` for suspicious hardware mixer settings (select correct card, use left/right arrows to show more mixers). You can also use `amixer -cX contents` to see more mixers (not all are displayed in `alsamixer`), where `X` is the number of your card as shown in `aplay -l`.

Use `speaker-test` (or `pasuspender speaker-test`) for more testing. If it works under ALSA, it must be a Pulseaudio problem. If you can't make it work under ALSA, put output of `lspci -nn`, `amixer -cX contents` and `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec\#*` into a pastebin or similar, and edit question with the link.

**Edit**

1) If I understand it correctly, the Startech USB/DP to HDMI adapter routes the digital signals, and *in addition* provides a 2-channel USB soundcard that drives the analog sound HDMI pins. Please verify this with `lsusb` (a device should show up), `aplay -l` (you should see a USB soundcard), and make sure you **don't** use this soundcard for output (but you probably did, just ruling out possible gotchas).

BTW, this setup is more complicated then it needs to be. The digital DP and HDMI signals are identical, it's the just the connector layout that's different, so a simple cheap passive adapter like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B071KX2JL8) would have been sufficient.

2) The Amazon page of the Extractor says

> Supports 3 modes of EDID management for audio formats, can switch among built-in EDID (2CH/5.1CH) and external EDID (TV).

Googling for the [manual](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/1300000-1399999/001376145-an-01-en-SPEAKA_HDMI_DIGITAL_AUDIO_KONVERTER.pdf) finds that there is a switch with options `PASS`, `2CH`, `5.1CH`. This must be set to `5.1CH`, in option `PASS` it will uses the mode of the connected TV/monitor, which may just be "stereo".

3) I assume you connect the 6 channel RCA analog audio output of the Extractor directly to your speakers, possibly via a analog amplifier? Or is the S/PDIF output connected to something else (another possible source of the error)?

**Edit**

Ok, current theory: Your deembedder produces an EDID with audio configuration information. For some reason, the 5.1 EDID doesn't work correctly, and is interpreted as allowing only stereo. That's why you see a 5.1 option without the deembedder connected, and when you connect it, it disappears, and you get only stereo.

So let's look at the EDID. I googled some specs (CEA-861-E), so I can try to decode it manually (and you can, too, if you want). Look into `/sys/class/drm/card-*/edid`, there should be files for every video output connector. You should have two of those that are not empty (test with `cat`, you'll see binary "garbage"): Your monitor and your deembedder. Do a hexdump, e.g.

```
hexdump -C /sys/class/drm/card1-HDMI-A-1/edid
```

and edit question to include hexdumps of EDIDs for all 3 switch settings (5.1, 2, PASS with an external TV connected via HDMI to the embeddeder if you can, so we can see of passthrough works), and also your monitor EDID for reference.

Hopefully this data will also have the audio extensions, if not, I'll have to think of some way to get them. I know one can override EDIDs, but I haven't done this before, so I'll have to look up this, too. And I'm not sure if it will override audio as well, but it's worth a try.

This is getting interesting. :-)

**Edit**

It's actually important to use `hexdump -C` instead of `hexdump`, because otherwise the bytes will get swapped. I corrected that with `dd conv=swab`. Here's the cleaned up version:

```
00000000  00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 34 ac c8 31 01 01 01 01  |........4..1....|
00000010  0d 13 01 03 80 a2 5b 78 2a 24 71 ae 4c 47 aa 26  |......[x*$q.LG.&|
00000020  10 50 54 21 08 00 d1 c0 8b c0 81 80 81 c0 66 c0  |.PT!..........f.|
00000030  4b c0 01 00 01 00 02 3a 80 18 71 38 2d 40 58 2c  |K......:..q8-@X,|
00000040  45 00 50 8d 63 00 00 1e 01 1d 80 18 71 38 2d 40  |E.P.c.......q8-@|
00000050  58 2c 45 00 50 8d 63 00 00 1e 00 00 00 fd 00 3b  |X,E.P.c........;|
00000060  3d 0f 44 11 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fc  |=.D...      ....|
00000070  00 4d 45 55 53 50 54 56 31 31 0a 20 20 20 01 6e  |.MEUSPTV11.   .n|
00000080  02 03 28 f1 47 90 22 20 05 04 03 01 23 09 7f 07  |..(.G." ....#...|
00000090  83 4f 00 00 6c 03 0c 00 21 00 a8 2d 00 00 00 00  |.O..l...!..-....|
000000a0  00 e3 05 03 01 e2 00 7f 01 1d 80 3e 73 38 2d 40  |...........>s8-@|
000000b0  7e 2c 45 80 50 8d 63 00 00 1e 01 1d 80 18 71 1c  |~,E.P.c.......q.|
000000c0  16 20 58 2c 25 00 50 8d 63 00 00 9e 01 1d 00 72  |. X,%.P.c......r|
000000d0  51 d0 1e 20 6e 28 55 00 50 8d 63 00 00 1e 8c 0a  |Q.. n(U.P.c.....|
000000e0  d0 8a 20 e0 2d 10 10 3e 96 00 50 8d 63 00 00 18  |.. .-..>..P.c...|
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18  |................|
```

I discovered that `edid-decode` (from the Debian package with the same name) does parse the CEA extension blocks, while `parse-edid` (from package `read-edid`) does not. So here's the relevant part:

```
Manufacturer: MEL Model 31c8 Serial Number 16843009
...
Monitor name: MEUSPTV11
...
CEA extension block
Extension version: 3
36 bytes of CEA data

  Audio data block
    Linear PCM, max channels 2
    Supported sample rates (kHz): 192 176.4 96 88.2 48 44.1 32
    Supported sample sizes (bits): 24 20 16
```

So, it's just stereo, and as it's the same for each switch setting, we've found the culprit: Either the switch is mechanically or electronically defect, and the microcontroller of the deembedder can't read the switch settings, or the microcontroller has a bug.

BTW, this EDID seems to be from a Mitsubishi TV.

Ways to override it: The EDID data gets translated to something called ELD ("EDID-like data"). This ELD is accessible via `/proc/asound/card*/eld#*`. You can `cat` these files, so find the one with valid data. You can also write name-value pairs to it, and it will change the ELD. So something like

```
echo 'sad0_channels 6' | sudo tee /proc/asound/card0/eld#3.2
```

with the correct path should change it to 6 channels. Verify with `cat` if it id, and if Pulseaudio gets updated about this change, you should have 5.1 sound.

Another option is to use the `CustomEDID` option in `xorg.conf`, see `man intel`. This needs a path to a file with binary EDID data. In the EDID, change the byte at `8c` from `09` to `0d` (that's the number of channels in the lower bits, part of the Short Audio Descriptor that happens to be in this position), and the checksum at `ff` from `18` to `14`. Changed data:

```
00000000  00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 34 ac c8 31 01 01 01 01
00000010  0d 13 01 03 80 a2 5b 78 2a 24 71 ae 4c 47 aa 26
00000020  10 50 54 21 08 00 d1 c0 8b c0 81 80 81 c0 66 c0
00000030  4b c0 01 00 01 00 02 3a 80 18 71 38 2d 40 58 2c
00000040  45 00 50 8d 63 00 00 1e 01 1d 80 18 71 38 2d 40
00000050  58 2c 45 00 50 8d 63 00 00 1e 00 00 00 fd 00 3b
00000060  3d 0f 44 11 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fc
00000070  00 4d 45 55 53 50 54 56 31 31 0a 20 20 20 01 6e
00000080  02 03 28 f1 47 90 22 20 05 04 03 01 23 0d 7f 07
00000090  83 4f 00 00 6c 03 0c 00 21 00 a8 2d 00 00 00 00
000000a0  00 e3 05 03 01 e2 00 7f 01 1d 80 3e 73 38 2d 40
000000b0  7e 2c 45 80 50 8d 63 00 00 1e 01 1d 80 18 71 1c
000000c0  16 20 58 2c 25 00 50 8d 63 00 00 9e 01 1d 00 72
000000d0  51 d0 1e 20 6e 28 55 00 50 8d 63 00 00 1e 8c 0a
000000e0  d0 8a 20 e0 2d 10 10 3e 96 00 50 8d 63 00 00 18
000000f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 14
```

Convert this to binary using `xxd -r`, and verify with `/sys/.../edid` and `/proc/.../eld...` that it does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: no change with killing Pulseaudio. The outputs to your commands are now incorporated in the edited question above.

Comment: Please add some details about your setup: What 5.1 Audio system do you use (exact brand and model, so I can google manuals)? What DP to HDMI converter (exact brand and model)? Why does the converter connect to USB (that it usually not necessary)? Does it provide some USB device (`lsusb`)? So far everything looks alright on the computer side, and because you are using a digital signal, really nothing should go wrong with the transfer, so I suspect some problem after the signal leaves the DP.

Comment: I use the USB-based converter because when I tried a regular DP to HDMI adapter (long time ago), there was no sound just video. I had to change the driver to a proprietary driver to get the sound that way, but with that the video quality became crappy. So I found that converter and have been using that since then (for two channel though up until now). I don't use an audio receiver, just a 5.1 de-embedder - esssentially, the PC is the receiver. I updated my post with the links to the specific products.

Comment: I got rid of the usb-based DP to HDMI  converter and got a regular straightforward DP to HDMI cable without USB. Still no changes. The last thing I found was that `pacmd list-sinks` still shows two channels so I think somehow that's where the problem is. I incorporated all this in the original post accordingly.

Comment: ...in addition to the above, yes, the deembedder has been always set at 5.1, and the extractor output goes to individual analog amiplifiers via RCA cables.

Comment: Just discovered something strange. At one point, I somehow rebooted the PC with 5.1 deembedder turned off. I went to `pavucontrol` and under the "Profile" in the configuration tab, I saw the option "Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output 5.1 (Unplugged)"!!! But there was no sound at all. So I turend the 5.1 deembedder on and rebooted the machine. The 5.1 HDMI option disappeared. Not sure what is going on, but with the deembedder turned on, the 5.1 option disappears.

Comment: there is a file called `edid` where you indicated, but it is empty. The output of `hexdump /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/edid` is now added to the original post.

Comment: you are a real expert in this. I think I will replace the deembedder with something else.

Comment: Just finding things out as I go along. That was a fun problem.